# Datables.net call function from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using datatables.net for creating table. I got select option cell. How to call function if drop down value changes? I tried various examples but nothing works. Thanks.

```
 {
            data: "priority",

            render: function(d,t,r){
                var $select = window.$("<select></select>", {
                    "id": r.fn + "priority",
                    "value": d
                });


                window.$.each(priority, function(k,v){
                    var $option = window.$("<option></option>", {
                        "text": v,
                        "value": v
                    });
                    if(d === v){
                        $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                    }
                    $select.append($option);
                });

                return $select.prop("outerHTML");
            }
        }
```

Comment: First you need to bind a function on Change event. In that change event you can fire an AJAX request. Simple thing.

Comment: I understand what i need to bind function on change event. Also i tried various thing and nothings works. Everything is "simple" in theory! :D

Comment: Create a running JS fiddle according to your requirement. I will help you in that. One more strange thing why are using window.$ object?